# Display GridView selected row data in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here I have a `GridView` which shows books details:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" BackColor="White"
                BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="5" ForeColor="#000066"
                GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                <Columns>

                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Red" SelectText="Select" HeaderText="Select" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now if I want to edit book details, there are also textboxes so when I click `Select` (`ShowSelectButton="true"`), column values should be populated in textboxes.

I've tried like this in `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` event but nothing happens when I click Select:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxID.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    textBoxTitle.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Comment: Does the event fire?

Comment: Yes, the page reloads when I click `Select`.

Comment: i think you want Labels data should be displayed in respective TextBox when use click on select

Comment: where is yours textBoxID and textBoxTitle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `Label`s of the row.

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = gridview1.SelectedRow;

    //now get the labels
    Label _LabelId = row.FindControl("LabelId") as Label;
    Label _LabelTitle = row.FindControl("LabelTitle") as Label;

    //get the values from labels and assign them to textboxes
    textBoxID.Text = _LabelId.Text;
    textBoxTitle.Text = _LabelTitle.Text;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works but is this effective because here I'm showing only two textboxes, while in `GridView` I have like 11 or 12 textboxes.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get your question

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBoxUserID.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
     TextBoxUserName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you cannot get the value because you are using ItemTemplateField change it for BoundField. You can use too DateKeyNames in your GridView with that Event SelectedIndexChanged

Answer (score 0):

In `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;      
if(gvRow != null)
           {
              Label lblId = gvRow.FindControl("LabelId") as Label;
              Label lblTitle = gvRow.FindControl("LabelTitle") as Label;
              if(lblId != null && lblTitle != null)
              {
                 textBoxID.Text = lblId.Text;
                  textBoxTitle.Text = lblTitle.Text;
               }
            }
```

Comment: will get error ` No overload for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'`

Comment: @Ganesh, I mean on the GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: will get error ` No overload for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar, seems like you have different issue. Can you post  your code?

Comment: from MSDN `void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)` then how you can access e.Row.RowType ??